# Ignore character in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to ignore 0 in the regex below. Currently, the regex returns an array and splitting the characters into n digits. I want the regex to ignore character 0.

```
var n = 2
var str = '123045';
var regex2 = new RegExp(`.{1,${n}}`,'g');
var reg = str.match(regex2)
```

Comment: What does your expected output look like? `["12", "34", "5"]` or `["12", "3", "45"]` or neither...?

Comment: You can replace all occurrence of that character with empty string then apply the regex to the result string.

Comment: yes ["12", "34","5"] is the expected output

Comment: @YazanWYusuf can you give an example ?

Comment: @BoatengKwekuAmpomahFrederic you can do something like `str.replace(/0/g, '').match(regex2);` to follow Yazan's suggestion

Comment: @NickParsons Please consider posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is by removing the `0` before you perform your match. This can be done by using `.replace()` like so:

```js
const n = 2
const str = '123045';
const regex2 = new RegExp(`.{1,${n}}`, 'g');
const reg = str.replace(/0/g, '').match(regex2);

console.log(reg); // [‘12’, ‘34’, ‘5’]
```

To ignore leading zeros, you can match for `0` followed by `n` amount of digits for each element in your matched array (using `.map()`) and `.replace()` this with the remaining digits by capturing them in a group, and using the group as the replacement:

```js
const n = 2
const str = '123045';
const regex2 = new RegExp(`.{1,${n}}`, 'g');

const reg = str.match(regex2).map(m => m.replace(/0(\d+)/g, '$1')).join('').match(regex2);

console.log(reg); // [‘12’, ‘30’, ‘45’]
```

Comment: what if I only want to ignore leading zeros. example, i want to get 12, 30, 45

Comment: @BoatengKwekuAmpomahFrederic you can use `.map()` and replace anything with a leading zero with the remaining digits

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use replace,

But if you want to do it using regex try `(?!0)[\d]` It shall give you matches 1,2,3,4,5